# pdf/Tikz Undefined Control Sequence

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors

I am drawing a Picture using TikZ with two `\draw` commands.
The first one works but on the second LaTeX claims

```
! Undefined control sequence. l.44 \draw (0,2) -- (-.5,2);
```

**What can I do to fix that...**
*Thanks in the preface*

**EDIT: MWE**

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikz}
    % First the house
    \draw [thick,color=gray] (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (1,3) -- (2,2) -- (2,0) -- cycle (0,2) -- (2,2);
    % This command doesnt work...
    \draw (0,1) -- (-.5,1);
\end{tikz}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: The previos TikZ command is ended correctly with an ';'

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! Please provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The `tikz` package defines a `\tikz` macro, but no `tikz` environment. Did you mean `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}`?

Comment: Instead of posting additional information, edit your your question to include the additional information there.

Comment: Great, it works... Thank you Jubobs. But why did the first command work?

Comment: The first command did work because `\begin{tikz}` is issuing a `\tikz` comand and this grabbed the first `\draw`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this. It should work.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
% First the house
\draw [thick,color=gray] (0,0) -- (0,2) -- (1,3) -- (2,2) -- (2,0) -- cycle (0,2) -- (2,2);
% This command DOES work!
\draw (0,1) -- (-.5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: **Thank you**  but the mistake was using a `tikz` environment rather than an `tikzpicture` environment...